# how to make color like default tooltip of input

Tags: css

I have a kendotooltip in my project when i hover I would like the color is same as default tooltip of input like this (`<a title="default color"></a>`). I edit color of kendo tooltip but it's not the same color.
This is my kendo tooltip color:

```
.k-tooltip-username {
   background-color: #FFFFFF !important; 
   border: solid 1px #919191 !important;
   border-radius: 0px;
   box-shadow: inset;
}
```

The color of text is not same as default of input and box-shadow is not appear.
This is image of kendotooltip:

[image]

This is image that I expected:

[image]

This is example:
https://jsfiddle.net/wpnj3gzn/

Please help me, Thanks.

Comment: So you want #picture1 to be the same as #picture2?

Comment: Yes The #picture1 need to same as #picture2.

Answer (score 0):

```
.k-tooltip-username {
   background-color: #FFFFFF !important; 
   border: solid 1px #ddd;
   border-radius: 0px;
   box-shadow: inset;
   box-shadow:2px 2px 2px #ddd;
   color:#ddd;
}
```

Something like that - I don't know what colour the grey is exactly.